# local host settings in Apache php.ini file

Tags: php, apache

I really appreciate any help as I have am just starting out with local servers.

The goal is to install demo content for my theme from theme.co/X

The instructions are to change some settings to allow the content to be installed.

I am using Xampp to create a local host and have managed to install wordpress (YAY!)

the instructions are to do the following:

> Hi Kirk,
>
> Thanks for reaching out!
>
> It is hard for us to determine the issue why you can’t install demo content in your localhost. I suggest that you change these settings in your local server.
>
> allow_url_fopen = On
> upload_max_filesize = 512M
> post_max_size = 512M
> max_execution_time = 300
> max_input_time = 300
> max_allowed_packet = 16Mb
> innodb_log_file_size = 128mb
> You can also check the error when you fresh f12 and go to console log tab.
>
> Hope that helps.
>
> Thank you.

I have assumed that this is to be done by editing the PHP.ini file that I have found in the apache settings drop down in Xampp.

I used "cntl + F" to find the the settings and have changed the ones I could find.the following two do not exist and if I add them Myslq crashes instantly after starting, then if I delete them it will still not run and due to my limited knowlege the only way I can rectify it is to reinstall Xampp, I will safe the original on the next attempt!

> max_allowed_packet = 16Mb
> innodb_log_file_size = 128mb

This is turning in to a long read so I won't copy the whole file but would really apreaciate your help!

Thank you

Ben

I tried editing the Apache php.ini file but am not shure if this is the correct thing to do.

profesionals oftern assume that others have as much knowlege as they do which can oftern lead to newbies struggling to follow simple instructions

Answer (score 0):

I found out that some of the settings needed to be changed in the myslq file and not in the apache file. Gpt chat helped me with it and I am now good to go!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).